# How do you externalize a spring filter-chain?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Due to cross-platform constraints, I'm trying to externalize the filter chain in spring security.  While it works great when I specify the filter list as a string literal, if I try to use the PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer to move the filters string out into a properties file, using this code:

```
<security:filter-chain pattern="/**/*auth=kerberos*"
            filters="${kerberosFilters}"/>
```

I receive the following error message:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource 

[config/common/security/spring-security.xml]: 
Cannot resolve reference to bean 'httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,spnegoExceptionTranslationFilter,filterSecurityInterceptor' 
while setting bean property 'filterChainMap' with key [/**/*auth=kerberos*] with key [0]; 
    nested exception is 
        org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
            No bean named 
                'httpSessionContextIntegrationFilter,logoutFilter,spnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter,securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,spnegoExceptionTranslationFilter,filterSecurityInterceptor' 
            is defined
```

It looks like when read from a properties file, Spring is trying to treat the entire string as a single bean name.

Is there any way to get around this, or is it a limitation of the Spring framework?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if something like this would work? (This is untested.)

```
<property name="filterList">
    <list ref="${kerberosFilters}"/>
</property>
```

Comment: Given that this is namespaced, I'm not sure how I would put that into the xml configuration.  Any ideas?